# JavaScript Worker - parallel writing to console

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-worker

According to numerous tutorials and documentations (e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp), JavaScript's `new Worker(...)` should create a new thread in the browser and run the `...` script in parallel. I have tested a few examples and it really seems that those Workers work in my browser (Chrome 31.0.1650.63 m).

So I tried to make a simple script and have a look at the amazing opportunity to use multithreading in JavaScript. Let's have a look at it:

```
function main()
{
    var newThread = new Worker("worker.js");
    writeToConsole();
}

function writeToConsole()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        console.log("main thread");
    }
}
```

**worker.js**:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    console.log("second thread");
}
```

What a similar code would do in a language like C++ [e.g. [SFML Threads](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/system-thread.php)] is something like this:

```
main thread
main thread
second thread
main thread
second thread
...
```

However when I run the `main()` function in my browser, it first writes `main thread` twenty times, then the `main` function returns (undefined) and then it logs twenty times the `second thread` message.

[image: Chrome Debug]

I guess I am missing something important here about how [Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker) really works. Or maybe is the problem caused by using the `console.log()`?

Comment: I found out that if I give a lot of work to the second thread (worker), e.g. calculating billions of square roots, I can make them log the strings concurrently overlapping each other, which proves that Worker really runs in another thread. However with the primitive example described above, the overlapping writing to the console does not happen.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specification or set of requirements around how the console.* methods work -- they are not officially part of
JavaScript, but are instead added to JS by the hosting environment .
So, different browsers and JS environments do as they please, which can sometimes lead to confusing behavior.
In particular, there are some browsers and some conditions that console.log(..) does not actually immediately output
what it's given. The main reason this may happen is because I/O is a very slow and blocking part of many programs (not
just JS). So, it may perform better (from the page/UI perspective) for a browser to handle console I/O asynchronously in
the background, without you perhaps even knowing that occurred.

If you run into this rare scenario, the best option is to use breakpoints in your JS debugger instead of relying on
console output. The next best option would be to force a "snapshot" of the object in question by serializing it to a string ,
like with JSON.stringify(..) .